# Integrate product of x^s and log(x)

Tags: calculus, self-learning

Let

$$ f(x) = 1 - (1-c\log (F(x)))^s\\
g(x) = \log(\frac{a}{x})
$$

for some positive integers $s$, $c$, and some real-valued function $F(x)$. $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm. One can think about $f(x)$ as the minimum outcome of $s$ independent draws of a random variable with distribution $c\log (F(x))$.

I'm trying to get the expected value of $g(x)$, given the minimum of $s$ draws. That is, I need to integrate

$$ \int f'(x)g(x) dx$$

for some positive real number $a$. I know that $g'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, and I am aware of the integral trick $\int u'v = uv - \int v'u$. However, I fail to see how I could use that. There's no substitution trick that I could think of that makes sense here.

How could I proceed? Note that this is not a homework assignment, so a closed form solution to the expression is not guaranteed.

I don't believe it is useful (because it doesn't have a nice structure), but here's F(x) for two real numbers $d,e$:

$$ F(x) = \frac{dx}{x-e}$$

Comment: Ok I gather this is not homework. So I can assume that there is a result? or at least some direction? and at the very least some more information about $F(x),p$. Then maybe I can attempt to look at it.

Comment: @Chinny84 The $p$ inside $g'(x)$ was a typo which came from translating my original and more complicated problem to this one. I fixed that and added $F(x)$. W.r.t. how to think about this, $ c \log F(x)$ is the distribution of some random variable $x$. $f(x)$ is then the distribution of the minimum of $s$ draws of $x$. Then, you can think of the integral as the expected value of $g(x)$, given the minimum of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

FooBar.

We have: $ f(x) = 1 - \left( 1 - c \cdot \log(F(x)) \right)^s \Leftrightarrow f'(x) =-s \cdot (1 - c \cdot \log(F(x)))^{s-1} \cdot \left( - \frac{c}{F(x) \cdot \ln (10) } \right) \cdot F'(x)  $, assuming $ \log(F(x)) = \log_{10}( F(x)) $.

Then:

$ \int f'(x) \cdot g(x) dx = \frac{s}{\ln(10)}\int (1 - c \cdot \log(F(x)))^{s-1} \cdot \frac{c \cdot F'(x)}{F(x)} \cdot \log \left( \frac{a}{x} \right) dx $

Now: $ F(x) = \frac{dx}{x-e} \Leftrightarrow F'(x) = \frac{d \cdot (x-e) - dx \cdot 1}{(x-e)^2} = \frac{dx - de - dx}{(x-e)^2} = -\frac{de}{(x-e)^2} $

And thus we have:

$ \large{\frac{s}{\ln(10)} \cdot \int (1 - c \cdot \log \left( \frac{dx}{x-e} \right))^{s-1} \cdot -\frac{c \cdot \left( \frac{de}{(x-e)^2}\right)}{\frac{dx}{x-e}} \cdot \log \left( \frac{a}{x} \right) dx  \\\\ = -\frac{s \cdot c}{\ln(10)} \cdot \int \left(1 - c \cdot \log \left( \frac{dx}{x-e} \right)\right)^{s-1} \cdot \frac{e}{(x-e)^2 \cdot x}  \cdot \log \left( \frac{a}{x} \right) dx}$

I don't see how one can proceed from here on out without knowing the values of the variables.

Kind regards,
Pedro